# Angularjs Confirm Password directive: why it does not see keyboard inputs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building my own 'Confirm Password' directive in Angular.js. I got my inspiration from this [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBEagw).

My directive:

```
directives.directive('pwCheck', function(){
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
        var pw1 = attrs.pwCheck;
        var pw2 = attrs.ngModel;
        scope.$watchGroup([pw1,pw2],function(value){                                                                                           
            console.log(value);                                                                                                                
            ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', value[0] === value[1]);                                                                               
        });                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                             
});
```

My form:

```html
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="newpassword" placeholder="Type your new password" ng-model="newpassword" 
ng-pattern="/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/"
ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" ng-required="" />
```

and:

```html
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="renewpassword" id="renwewpassword" placeholder="Type your new password again"  
ng-model="renewpassword" ng-required="" pw-check="newpassword" />
```

However, `watchGroup` does not seem to catch changes (keystrokes) in "newpassword".
The `console.log()` in the directive will print `undefined` for `value[0]`, while it prints the correct input for `value[1]`.

I can't figure out where the problem is. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/87non2k5/) with your code and it seems to be working fine. But remember, the `ng-model` of your first input will not be populated unless all of the validation is satisfied:

```
ng-pattern="/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20"
```

If you test with a valid password e.g. `ABCDabcd1234`, you'll see that both of the values are populated and that keystrokes in both inputs are picked up.

From the [Angular Forms guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms):

> The value of ngModel won't be set unless it passes validation for the
>   input field. For example: inputs of type email must have a value in
>   the form of user@domain.

Comment: Thanks @sheilak, that was the issue: "the ng-model of your first input will not be populated unless all of the validation is satisfied"!